# Can I add certificate management console to Windows server Administrative Tools

Tags: windows, certificate, mmc

Windows Server has always had an MMC snap-in for certificates, but it is not visible.

I would like to add an icon to the administrative tools control panel so that administrators without a lot of experience can easily open the certificates console.

Is there a way to do that?

I know that you can load the snap-in and then save a .MSC file in your user profile.  While that is nice, it is not what I am looking for.  I have hundreds of servers and dozens of administrators.

Since at least Windows Server 2012 R2 Microsoft has shipped certlm.msc in the Windows\System32 folder.  I know that I can hit Win+R and type certlm.msc to launch the 'local machine' certificate console.  While that is even nicer, it is not what I am looking for.  Many of my system administrators are inexperienced.  I need something dead simple.  *pointy, clicky, go* is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Administrative Tools* shell folder under control panel opens up the contents of the folder `C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools` which can have whatever additional items you need pushed to it via policy.

It really seems like this is a workaround however. This is going taking advantage of this folder not being updated to the new win10 modern ui. Documenting / training your folks to use the new interface is a much better option.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for but you had a mistake.  Start Menu is under C:\ProgramData not C:\Users\All Users.
Interestingly, on Server 2012 R2 the folder is at **Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools**   but on windows 10 the folder is at **Start Menu\Programs\Windows Administrative Tools**

Answer (score 1):

Create the .MSC file you are talking about, then push this file on `c:\users\public\desktop` via Group Policy Preferences (`Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Windows Settings -> Files`)

The file will show up on the desktop.